# Why are a single SET query and several appropriate separate SET queries not equivalent?

Tags: mysql

I test with the following simplified queries that are similar to my real queries.

```
mysql> SET @a=100; SET @b=@a; SELECT @a, @b; SELECT @a:=@a+3;
...
+------+------+
| @a   | @b   |
+------+------+
|  100 |  100 |
+------+------+
...
```

It returns the correct result for me because `a` is equal to `b` and equal to `100`. But I use 4 queries and several variables require several queries.

According to `help SET` I create query with the syntax `SET variable_assignment [, variable_assignment] ...` and execute for the first time:

```
mysql> SET @a=100, @b=@a; SELECT @a, @b; SELECT @a:=@a+3;
...
+------+------+
| @a   | @b   |
+------+------+
|  100 | NULL |
+------+------+
...
```

Why does `a` not equal to `b` and equal to `NULL`?

The second and next executions of the same query give this result:

```
mysql> SET @a=100, @b=@a; SELECT @a, @b; SELECT @a:=@a+3;
...
+------+------+
| @a   | @b   |
+------+------+
|  100 |  103 |
+------+------+
...
```

Why does `a` not equal to `b` and equal to `103` instead of `100`?
How does it work in this situation?

Comment: Does `SET` guarantee left to right order of evaluation? Otherwise @b=@a may get evaluated before @a=100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that it works the same as an `UPDATE` statement. In the second example the value of @a before the statement is the value that's assigned. The whole operation is handled as an atomic unit.

The documentation on this topic appears not to cover this case but there is a "user comment" at the bottom that touches on the exact same scenario.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-statement.html

UPDATE: I think this issue is addressd in this bug report:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74246

Comment: Almost worth raising a doc bug for this.

Comment: @Lightness I found another bug report. I'm not sure if a documentation report is also necessary.

Comment: I still think the expected behaviour needs to be documented.

Comment: Do they generally update the documentation in parallel with bug fixes?

Comment: I don't know. Hopefully! But in this case there is no documentation to update, so I think it's a new bug to add it.